# Best way to heatsink many exposed copper polygons, avoiding electrical shorts

Tags: heatsink, power-dissipation, insulation

I'm working on a special type of lamp that uses 10 high-power SMD LEDs and 10 low-power TH LEDs. The heat dissipation will be an issue, so almost the entirety of the PCB is copper pours for the SMD LEDs. The PCB is somewhat small, but that's constrained by the optics of the lamp. Here's the back side of the PCB:

[image: LED PCB]

Each copper polygon serves as the "track" between two adjacent LEDs on the string. The 10 LEDs are in series. On the front side of the PCB, the polygons are essentially the same, and are heavily stitched to the equivalent polygons on the back side. Each LED has about 2.6cm² of cooling area on the front side, plus another 2.6cm² on the back side.

Each LED will dissipate around 4W of heat at full power. I will of course implement thermal monitoring and thermal throttling to prevent damage to the LEDs, but in general I want to heatsink the PCB as good as possible, and I have never done this with so many pads at different potentials.

My current idea, which is based on reading on the internet, not actual experience, is to do the following:

- use a mica sheet (0.5mm thick, 2.5W/mK) and carefully cut it to the circular shape, and drill 10 holes where the leads of the low-power TH LEDs are
- use an aluminium sheet (1.5mm thick) with the same shape, on top of the mica (again with over-large holes for the TH LEDs)
- place a big CPU heatsink and fan on top of the aluminium sheet
- use electrically non-conductive silicone thermal grease on each interface (PCB-mica, mica-sheet, sheet-CPU heatsink)

But I'm not sure this is the best way, or if there aren't any caveats I'm not aware of.

## Question

How do you heatsink a PCB with many copper polygons, which all need cooling, and are all at different potentials?

Comment: You're looking for thermal pads.

Comment: @TimWilliams, would you care to elaborate? I have no experience with thermal pads either. E.g. do you suggest placing a big 65x65mm thermal pad, or cutting 10 small pieces? Does the aluminium shim then remain or is no longer needed, as the thermal pads are thick enough? Etc.

Comment: One seems easy enough. Soft materials are available which conform to the mating surfaces with little pressure (or are tacky themselves). I don't understand the placement/orientation of the mix (TH/SM LEDs) but it sounds like you will be able to fit everything together in a more or less flat joint already, so a thermal/gap pad seems perfectly suited (without the hassle of mica and grease).

Comment: @TimWilliams, I eventually used thermal pads as you suggest, and it worked beautifully. Feel free to turn your comment into an answer :)